# How to change user account settings for match step in fastlane?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, fastlane, fastlane-match

How could I easily change the match configuration so it continues working with a new user?

We had a person who was account owner whose account was used to perform the build via FastLane. Since Apple introduced the new 2-factor authentication which is mandatory for the account owners we had to either authorize computer via 2fa occasionally or use some other account which is not of account owner role. We want to change the user to the specialized account only for fastlane builds.  I have a feeling I will need to nuke everything and start from scratch but I would rather get some input before doing that.
I already created accounts needed for apple developer portal and for iTunesconnect. I changed fastfile, matchfile, deliverfile and .env but it always pulls the old user somehow.
We are using the git for storing credentials but as far as I know I should not have to touch anything there since it's only used for sync.

I tried using

```
fastlane match development
```

And it verifies on the portal but then it installs old users certificate.

Comment: Did you create a completely new user or did you give a new user access to the old user's certificates? (Not sure if that is even possible) If you really have to set up everything completely new, then you best start with a new match repository so everything is set up from zero. `nuke` is a way to clean an existing account's data, so I don't think this would help here.

Comment: I created a totally new "service user". I am already fairly certain I would have to recreate everything from scratch with `match init` so this could work. Since it has to recreate provisioning profiles and add new developer certificate in them too. Just wanted to check before performing the destructive operation

Comment: I would suggest asking at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues as well.